# Sharing Internet Connection with PdaNet

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, internet-sharing

So I'm using my mobile provider to have internet in my home.

To do this I use PdaNet (http://pdanet.co/a/) via USB and works perfectly.

**Now, I want to share the internet connection from my Mac to all my devices using WiFi.**

Sharing settings

[image]

By simply sharing it via Sharing shortcut on System preferences it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sharing *From* presumably your phone, as you mentioned USB, then *To* Wifi.

You have to switch sharing off to change settings, btw.

Comment: Actually Ethernet adaptor (en7) is my phone, check it https://imgur.com/a/BEKNGa9

Comment: Then I've no idea what's going on - how come you're showing 4 different iPhone connection & another Ethernet, as well as a LAN connection? Have you isolated what each of those actually is?

Comment: I have updated the link with one image that clarify this https://imgur.com/a/BEKNGa9 (don't pay attention to the iPhone USB stuff, the connection is handled as a Ethernet by PDAnet)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a direct solution for this, so what I did was to install **NetSharePro** and use it along with **PdaNet**. My Mac connected to **PdaNet** via USB cable (so I could push to Github, etc) and then connected all my other devices to the WiFi generated by **NetSharePro**.